# How to convert a PDE on a sphere to a PDE in $\mathbb{R}^n?$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable

Consider the following equation,
$$\Delta_{\mathbb{S}^n} u + u = u^3 $$
on the unit Sphere $\mathbb{S}^n.$ How do we convert this equation to an equation in $\mathbb{R}^{n}?$ I read about Stereographic projections that is a map of the following form $F:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{S}^n\setminus\{(0,\cdots, 1)\}$,
$$F(x) = \left(\frac{2x}{1+|x|^2},\frac{1- |x|^2}{1+|x|^2}\right).$$
But I am not sure how to come up with a PDE such that if $u$ solves the equation written above on the sphere, then $\hat{u}=G[u(F(x))])$ solves a PDE in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Any ideas/comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that what you are asking is ill-defined (and non-trivial). Your equation cannot necessarily be posed on the whole of Euclidean space without further decay/radiation condition on the solution. In other words the spaces in which you can solve this equation are not the same in Euclidean space and on the sphere. Being a compact boundary-less manifold, the sphere is very special with a completely different topology which does affect the type of solutions. Here, pullback the problem to coordinate charts: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431421/solution-to-a-pde-on-a-manifold

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solution to a PDE on a manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1431421/solution-to-a-pde-on-a-manifold)

Comment: @E.Schulz Thanks, I was interested in trying to do something similar as shown here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.08203.pdf around eqn (1.6)

Comment: @E.Schulz not really, I am just wondering I am interested solving the PDE locally, but really in the sense of what I saw in the preprint I shared above

Comment: Hey, I wonder if you have some new thoughts on this topic, because I also want to do something like this thesedays but I didn't see many references. @Student

Comment: @YuxuanLi, hey I have managed to figure this out but somehow the results I wanted to prove are too hard since the moving planes etc. does not work